# Align text left and right in Android

Tags: java, android, alignment, android-tablelayout

I currently have a problem with aligning text(Left & Right) in Android...
I want to make a receipt that looks like below format.

Nasi Putih               RM 1.00

Nasi Tomato           RM 1.20

Nasi Hujan Panas   RM 1.50

Total Price :             RM 3.70

Below is my code:

```
      if(nsPutih==true)
      {

          tvOutput1.setText("Nasi Putih RM 1.00");
          tvOutput1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          price+=1;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (nsTomato==true)
      {
          tvOutput2.setText("Nasi Tomato RM 1.20");
          tvOutput2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1.2;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if(nsHjanPanas==true)
      {
          tvOutput3.setText("Nasi Hujan Panas RM 1.50");
          tvOutput3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1.5;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
```

I want the receipt to be like IN A TABLE which is very well aligned (In manner, that all those Nasi elements are aligned left and the price is right aligned.) Help me please!

Below is the code for xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="40dp" >

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textB"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



   </LinearLayout>


   </ScrollView></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For `Price` you have to use different `TextViews`.  Align Textviews like columns. First for `Text` and Second for `Rs.`

Comment: You don't have any layoutParams specified. It's much easier to create a layout in xml. You could use a GridView (which is what I would do) but you could also use a TableView or a combination of LinearLayouts  using a vertical LinearLayout with some nested horizontal LinearLayouts.  If you do have a layout defined in XML then please post it.

Comment: Use two texfields... name & cost respectively... For more precise use Table Layout...

Answer (score 0):

You XML, you need to add two textview in a row, one for the Nasi elements and another for the price elements.

Try something like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="40dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And change your java code to match the names of the widgets set in the XML. Something like below, just watch-out and make necessary changes wherever required.

```
if(nsPutih==true)
      {

          tvOutput1.setText("Nasi Putih");
          tvOutput2.setText("RM 1.00");
          tvOutput1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          tvOutput2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          price+=1;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          tvOutput2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (nsTomato==true)
      {
          tvOutput3.setText("Nasi Tomato");
          tvOutput3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          tvOutput4.setText("RM 1.20");
          tvOutput4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          price+=1.2;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          tvOutput4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if(nsHjanPanas==true)
      {
          tvOutput5.setText("Nasi Hujan Panas");
          tvOutput5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          tvOutput6.setText("RM 1.50");
          tvOutput6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

          price+=1.5;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          tvOutput6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
```

I hope it helps. Still have doubts with the code, please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

codePG's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26419147/4672107) won't align the items on the right. This will:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"/>
</LinearLayout>
```